# Grails Controller and URL Mapping Magic

Tags: grails, grails-controller, url-mapping, grails-3.0

Grails **3.0.1** here. I'm looking to accomplish a specific URL/controller structure. My app deploys at the root context (`/`), meaning locally it runs as `http://localhost:8080`, and non-locally as `http://someserver.example.org`.

I want everything under `/app/*` to be authenticated and considered to be part of the "core app" (requires login). Anything outside of that URL is considered to be a part of the public website (unauthenticated). However, I want `/app/` itself to just be a placeholder of sorts; I do **not** want it to be a Grails controller. Hence:

- `http://localhost:8080/app` may be configured (`UrlMappings`?) to bring up a login page
- `http://localhost:8080/app/<controller>/<action>` follows typical Grails controller/action suit, and would invoke the correct controller action

Hence `http://localhost:8080/app/order/create` would be authenticated and, if logged in, invoke the `OrderController#create` action, which might render a `createOrder.gsp`.

I'm wondering what the Grails 3.x approach is to:

1. Allowing `/app/` to exist, but not as a controller (like I said, perhaps just redirecting/mapping to a login page)
2. Allowing anything underneath `/app/` to follow the controller/action paradigm

Thoughts on how to implement this?

---

#### Update

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/app/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
            ???
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails has the possibility to declare namespaces for Controllers. With this, you can put all your controllers under the namespace 'app', which should result in exactly your second question. See [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#namespacedControllers) for more details.

The security restriction then be accomplished with normal spring security settings (`@Secured` e.g).

Comment: Thanks @Mario David (+1) - I think that puts me in the ballpark vicinity, but would I just put the following declaration in every controller: `static namespace = 'app'`, or would I have to do something to `UrlMappings.groovy`? Can you give me a quick pseudo-code example? Thanks again!

Comment: as i'm thinking a little about it, it is not even necessary to use the namespace feature. Because this is only useful if you have different namespaces. What you actually want to do is to define another UrlMapping besides the normal one like so: `"/app/$controller/$action?/$id?"`. With this you don't need to use namespaces, because there are no different namespaces for the same controller name.

Comment: Thanks again @Mario David (+1) - please see my update and code snippet. I *believe* I've done what you are suggesting, if so: (1) why leave the normal/original mapping in place (**what does that achieve**)? (2) What does this new mapping achieve (**why /app/**)? And (3) What doe I put as the body instead of `???` ? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have any controllers, that you want to be accessible not through `/app/**` ? If this is the case, then i would make a UrlMapping for these controllers explicitly. Then you can replace the generic mapping `"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"` with `"/app/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"` and then add non-app controllers like this: `"/customers" (resources: "customer")`. The ??? can be filled with potential constrains or remove it.